# Невозможно применить кириллический шрифт dearpygui

Tags: python, gui, dearpygui

Я использую библиотеку dearpygui.

У меня есть шрифт, который включает в себя кириллицу.

```py
with dpg.font_registry():
    dpg.add_font(r"fonts\ru_alt.ttf", 18, default_font=True)
```

При отображении английского текста проблем не возникает.

[image: Англ. текст]

Но при попытке вывести текст на кириллице, выводятся знаки вопроса

[image: Русский текст]

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение из официальной документации:
[тык](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/stable_08/api-reference/fonts.html#loading-specific-unicode-characters)

```py
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font(r"fonts\ru_alt.ttf", 18, default_font=True):
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чуть чуть дополню предыдущий ответ с новыми реалиями (ну или просто моими проблемами кода):

```
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font(f'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbi.ttf', 13, default_font=True, id="Default font"):
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
dpg.bind_font("Default font")
```